# Parsing XML data with self-closing tags in Python

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I can parse XML data by using the tags when they are opening and closing.
Like `<link>https://www.nba.com/bucks/</link>`

in code this becomes,

```
link = item['link']
```

How do I parse a self closing tag?

```
<enclosure url="https://www.nba.com/bucks/sites/bucks/files/styles/media_thumbnail/public/middleton_3point_tw.jpg?itok=eiU05Btp" length="37714" type="image/jpeg" />
```

Also how do I only get the image url and drop everything after `?` in the URL?

Comment: How are you "parsing" it? I hope not by hand (e.g., regex)... You should be using an XML parser if you aren't already, then it shouldn't matter at all whether they're closed or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use an XML parser such as https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

- XPaths define standard expressions for identifying and extracting elements/tags in an xml document
- Using XPaths with a good xml parser you can easily find any element in a document. For example the xpath to find all **enclosure** elements in a document would be **".//enclosure"**
- If you are parsing alot of XML XPaths are well worth reading about. Here is a great starting tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

For example you could do:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('your_xml_file.xml')
enclosures = tree.findall(".//enclosure") # Use the XPath to find all enclosure elements 
for enclosure in  enclosures:
    print(enclosure.attrib)
```

#### Output

```
{'url': 'https://www.nba.com/bucks/sites/bucks/files/styles/media_thumbnail/public/middleton_3point_tw.jpg?itok=eiU05Btp', 'length': '37714', 'type': 'image/jpeg'}
```

You can then just split the url at the **?** to get your final output
For example

```
url = enclosure.attrib['url'].split('?')[0]
print(url)
```

#### Output

`https://www.nba.com/bucks/sites/bucks/files/styles/media_thumbnail/public/middleton_3point_tw.jpg`